# Multiple image file input in HTML5

Tags: html, google-chrome

Selecting one image file as follows works:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="files" name="files" />
```

Selecting multiple image files does not as it displays all the files in the sub-directory:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
```

Is this a Chrome bug or is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restart Google Chrome.  It seems that the MIME type is registered once per session.

Might be a feature?

Answer (score 0):

Normal.
The file picker does not allow selecting files on different directories.

That's what I know of windows, linux and Mac.

Comment: Is `image/*` really a directory?  Is it not a _type_?

Comment: image/* Is a MIME type. Does this mean that I didn't understand your question right?